# Equivalent of grep to awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to know the equivalent of

```
grep -oE '[^ ]+$' pathname
```

to awk or sed.
If someone can answer and explain that would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you think that command does and what you are trying to do with sed or awk. That way we can be sure that what we give you is what you actually want.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with `sed` or `awk` instead of `grep`? What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go over what your `grep` command does first:

- the `-o` tells `grep` to output only the matching part instead of the whole line
- the `-E` flag allows use of extended regular expressions
- `'[^ ]+$'` will match any non-space character repeated one or more times at the end of the line - basically a word at the end of the line.

Test run:

```
$ cat input.txt
to be or not to be
that is the question
$ grep -oE '[^ ]+$' input.txt                                      
be
question
```

Now, how can we do the same in `awk` ? Well that's easy enough considering that `awk` operates by default on space-separated entries of each line (we call them words - `awk` calls them fields). Thus we could print `$NF` with awk - take the `NF` variable for number of fields and treat it as referring to specific one. But notice that the `grep` command would only match non-blank lines, i.e. there is at least one word there. Thus, we need to a condition for `awk` - operate only on lines which have `NF` number of fields above zero.

```
awk 'NF{print $NF}' input.txt
```

It should be noted that GNU awk at least supports extended regex (I'm not familiar with others as extensively, so won't make claims about others). Thus we could also write a variation on cuonglm's answer:

```
$ awk '{if(match($0,/[^ ]+$/)) print $NF}' input.txt               
be
question
```

With GNU `sed` one can use extended regular expressions as well - that requires `-r` flag, but you can't simply use same regular expression. There's a need to use backreference with `\1`.

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                                          
to be or not to be
that is the question
blah 

$ sed -r -e 's/^.* ([^ ]+)$/\1/' input.txt                                                                             
be
question
blah
```

It is possible to obtain desired result with basic regular expression like so:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                    
to be or not to be
that is the question
blah 
$ sed 's/^.* \([^ ].*\)$/\1/' input.txt                           
be
question
blah
```

For more info, please refer to these posts:

- [can we print the last word of each line in linux using sed command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181425/85039)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31479/85039

Comment: very good and clear answer +1. (although there are minor behavior differences)

Comment: Yes, great explanation, but your examples are not 100% equivalent to the `grep`. I've been consistently and pedantically pointing out edge cases under all answers, so here's yours: `printf 'foo bar\tbaz\na b \n'`. Try that oen and compare your `sed` or `awk` and the OP's `grep`.

Answer (score 6):

`awk` is superset of `grep`, so you can use that `grep` pattern in `awk` as well:

```
awk '{match($0, "[^ ]+$"); if (RSTART > 0) print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

Comment: `awk` is superset of `grep` ? They're two separate utilities , with two separate purposes. Can you explain what you mean by that ?

Comment: @Serg: `awk` can do anything `grep` does, in standard version

Comment: it sure can do almost everything that `grep` does, but asserting that one utility is superset of another unrelated utility is just wrong. `grep` is line matching tool, `awk` is text processing language with C-like syntax - different animals.  Perl for instance can do anything awk can do and even more, but it's not a superset - it's a completely separate programming language.  Don't get me wrong, Your answer is perfectly fine as far as the `awk` code part, but just that phrase is just . . . wrong

Comment: @cuonglm, although not perfect your erased solutions were very interesting. YOu shoud not delete them!

Comment: @Serg Yes, so that's why I said it's superset, *line matching* is one of the task a *text processing* can do. See also this answer for similar mind http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303049/38906

Comment: @JJoao: I need spend more times to make it perfect, you and others still can view it in revision. It needs more document if there's no perfect solution, need to take time, I don't have it now.

Answer (score 4):

in awk:

```
awk 'NF>0 {print $NF}'     ## fails with end of line spaces; \thnaks{cuonglm}
```

```
awk '/[^ ]$/ {print $NF}'  ## fails with tabs in lasts field; \thanks{Terdon}
```

```
awk -F ' +'  '$NF {print $NF}'            ## too tricky
```

```
awk 'match($0,/[^ ]+$/,a){print a[0]}'    ## follows def. of grep -o
```

In sed:

```
sed -nr 's/(|.* )([^ ]+)$/\2/p'
```

\thanks{cuonglm}

and (why not?) in Perl

```
perl -nlE '/([^ ]+)$/ and say $1'
```

Comment: @terdon, you are an evil creature! ☺ ; `awk -F ' +' '$NF {print $NF}'` ?

Comment: Ooh, clever! Can't think of a way to break that one no :)

Comment: Use special examples is not good manner to compare with different language. I can say perl is much better at dealing with data than awk?

Comment: @utopiceexpress, Perl is a wonderful language (`perl -nle '/([^ ]+)$/ and print $1'`) but that was not the question...

Answer (score 0):

This is the sed-equivalent of what you are trying to do with grep:

```
# there is a space n a tab in the [...]
sed -ne '/[^  ]$/s/.*[    ]//p'

# this makes the code intent visually unambiguous
TAB=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\011'`; # tab
SPC=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\040'`; # space
h="[$SPC$TAB]";                 # whitespace
S="[^$TAB$SPC]";                # nonwhitespace

sed -ne "/$S\$/s/.*$h//p"

sed -ne "s/.*$h\($S$S*\)\$/\1/p"
```

Comment: No it isn't! That will print all lines of the file, not only those that have at least one non-space character before the end. All you're doing here is removing everything until the last space of a line. You then print everything.

Comment: Try `printf 'foo bar\tbaz\na b \n'`. Your first one will print an empty line and your second will print `b` and a space. This is harder than it looks, I know :)

Comment: I know, that's why I asked the OP to clarify and didn't answer. If you do answer, however, you need to make sure whatever command you propose gives the exact same output as `grep -oE '[^ ]+$'`. Your, admittedly very clever, solutions don't do that. Try `printf 'foo bar\tbaz\na\tb\n'` and pass through the `grep` and your `sed`s. I don't think you can do it in any other way than what [JJoao used](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354847/22222) with the `(|.* )`.

Comment: `sed -ne 's/[^ ][^ ]*$/\n&/;s/.*\n//p'` Assuming [^ ] => no space only as is the grep. This is for POSIX sed. There's no way to show an escaped newline on the RHS of s/// hence this.